# Make new columns in a DataFrame using a pandas column having dictionary inside

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

[image: Location gps]

Hello,

i want to have 2 columns : **longitude** and **latitude**
i dont know how to extract the values of those from the column **Location** 
i think the column **"Location"** is a **list of dictionaries** or **JSON type** that's why its causes problems.

**how** can i get latitude and longitude columns ?

Thanks in advance  !

Comment: Can you please confirm if the data is JSON or Dict?

Comment: i dont know how to do it but i think JSON or Dict is very similar

Comment: How do you build this DataFrame in the first place? Also, sharing screenshots of code/data is discouraged, please include those as text instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `json_normalize` if your column `location` are dictionaries:

```
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

print (pd.concat([df,json_normalize(df['location'])],axis=1))
```

If `location` is string representations of `dict`, use `ast.literal_eval`:

```
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
from ast import literal_eval

df["location"] = df["location"].apply(literal_eval)
print (pd.concat([df,json_normalize(df['location'])],axis=1))
```

Result:

```
                    location        BuildingType  lat  long
0  {'lat': 123, 'long': 456}      NonResidential  123   456
1  {'lat': 523, 'long': 756}      NonResidential  523   756
2  {'lat': 163, 'long': 496}  NonResidential COS  163   496
```

Comment: I tried the first with json_normalise i got this error : 'str' object has no attribute 'values'

Comment: and the second test with literal_evel i got this error : malformed node or string: <_ast.Name object at 0x0000021C2472F7F0>

Comment: That means your column values are neither valid dictionaries nor string representations of valid dictionaries. You need to clean up your data.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help ! any idea how can i clean the Location column ?

Comment: You can try looping through every item in your column and see which one is invalid, perhaps using a `try` clause.